# How to add server-side apis to Django admin website?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm creating a Django app that can be installed on any Django website as a reusable PyPi package, Lets name it locations app. It has its own models.py, admin.py and let's assume that the custom models of this app have the following tables:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And all these models are added to the admin website so users can access them from there.

What I need to do is to add an API that lists all Cities for a specific Country so that this API is used in the background every time the user selects a country when adding or editing a location so that it then shows a list of all cities in the currently selected country.

My problem is that if I define this API as a view in **locations/views.py** located somewhere by **locations/urls.py**. The URI of the API will be subject to the main urls.py of the website not only the *locations/urls.py** and the URI of the admin website as well might vary depending on the main urls.py. So how can I make sure the API will still be accessible regardless of whatever configurations in urls.py?

Does Django admin provide any custom APIs for this?

Comment: You can override “get_urls” in your model admin and add any custom urls/views you want. Obviously this will only work if the user of your package enables the admin

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're trying to do is something that resembles this https://github.com/garyburgmann/drf-firebase-auth. This is a Django app that can be installed and imported to the INSTALLED_APPS variables. It might help you on your project I suppose.